# Static Left Column With iframe Filling Remainder Right Side of Page

Tags: html, css, iframe

Since the depreciation of the HTML FRAMES tag I have been at a loss of how to create the same affect using iframe with divides. I have read through 20 solutions on StackOverflow and many other websites and can't seem to find exactly what I need.

I would like to have a static column on the left that is 200 pixels wide and fill the remaining page with an iframe. I would like it to also fill the height, (100%). The iframe needs to have a scroll bars.

The ifrane is off center and no mater what code I use I wind up with either no scroll bars or double scroll bars. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  body, html {
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background: #f3f3f3;
  }
  iframe {
   overflow:hidden;
   height:100%;
   width:100%
  }
  #leftcol {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   border: solid #0000ff 1px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   background: #ffffff;
  }
  #mainbody {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 200px;
   border: solid #ff0000 1px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   background: #ffffff;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="leftcol">Some text</div>
 <div id="mainbody"><iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://example.com/"></iframe> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Pt3Et/7/

Let me know if you needs are different

```
  body, html {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
     height: 100%;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    }
    iframe {
    float: right;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
    }
    #leftcol {
    border: solid red 1px;
    width: 200px;
     float: left;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
     }
    #mainbody {
    float: right;
    border: solid #ff0000 1px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 62%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution at Alex Robinson's site:
**[fu2k.org/alex/css/frames/iframe](http://fu2k.org/alex/css/frames/iframe)**
He places iframes in divs and uses CSS to manage them all. 
It works on different monitors with various resolutions. 
It also works when you resize. 
You can have static divs and resizing divs. 
View the source to examine the page.